Can a capacitor be used to close path between center-tap and shield instead of Bob-Smith (capacitor+resistor)?
I believe this has already been quite a controversial topic, but I'm wondering if just a capacitor can be used to direct the common-mode (CM) noise away from the center-taps (CT) of a CM choke back to shield (and not terminate it through Bob-Smith)? This can also be viewed as Bob-Smith with 0R resistor. Here the focus is specifically on PoE applications, where the CT is used for DC powering and the CT extends into other parts of the circuit. It seems that the 75Ohms might be an additional resistance for noise in its return path allowing it to possibly travel further through the circuit if there are some lower impedance path back to shield. I have read that the 75R represents the characteristics of the cabling, but I don't think that it is actually a defined parameter so its variable.

Why not both?
You can series a resistor and capacitor just fine.  The capacitor should be some 10s of nF, I suppose, so that its peak (AC) voltage during ESD is small (the 1nF still handles most of it) and the resistor dominates at most frequencies (where BS termination of the pairs is desired).
The CM impedance between pairs isn't controlled or specified normally, no, but it will be in the ballpark of 50-100Ω, for the same reason that random (unspecified and uncontrolled) [single] wires twisted together will place in the same range of impedance: the range of geometry and dielectric constant just isn't that wide, the impedance isn't that sensitive over such a range, and all that matters is the aspect ratio of the conductors.
An exact impedance match is not required, because the purpose is not to optimize signal quality (there is no intended signal content in the common mode), but to provide some damping and termination; even a 2:1 mismatch is still acceptable, because all that's really needed is some means to dissipate energy present in this mode [CM], whereas if it were allowed to resonate at high Q (strong reflections and thus standing waves from lack of termination), inevitable imbalance in the cable itself, magnetics, etc. would invite CM-DM mode conversion and thus affect immunity/emissions of the cable.
A capacitor alone cannot do, because it presents either a short circuit for short-duration transients / high frequencies, or at best a comparable impedance but only for frequencies near resonance, and in any case as a capacitor it's a conservative element: incident energy is reflected at a phase shift, and you get standing waves all the same.
But really, a meaningful and complete answer depends on the impedance your PoE tap presents, and a full schematic and EMC review are required to begin such an assessment.

Exactly!!!!!!!!
